# Model Validation Not Working on Multiple Models in Single View | in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I need to do validation in the view where I sent 2 different models. I implemented this to be able to use 2 different models in a single view.

Dish.cs

```
public class Dish
    {
        public int DishId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "req")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "req")]
        public string DishName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "req")]
        public string Description { get; set; } 
    }
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }     
    }
```

DishCategoriesModel.cs

```
public class DishCategoriesModel
    {
        public Dish Dish { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

Add.cshtml

```
@model DishCategoriesModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Dish.DishName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Dish.DishName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Dish.DishName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Dish.Category.CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="Dish.Category.CategoryId">
                    <option selected disabled>Select Category...</option>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.CategoryId">@item.CategoryName</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Category.CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Dish.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Dish.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Dish.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>          
          
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

DishController.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Add()
    {
        List<Category> categories = categoryService.GetAll();

        DishCategoriesModel model = new DishCategoriesModel
        {
            Categories = categories
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(DishCategoriesModel model)
    {  
        dishService.Add(model.Dish);
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I sent a single model to View, validations were working, but if I made it like above, it doesn't work. What is the right way?

Comment: The are 2 kinds of validations : client and server. I can't see that you are even trying to validate at the server side.  Why it should be working?

Comment: @Serge hi, my problem is that when I send a single model, the client side validation is working, but when I send more than one model, I can't get the same action.

Comment: Hi @MaykılSkofiyıld, any update?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any requirements on category , this is why this part is not working

Try to fix your Dish class by adding CategoryId:

```
public class Dish
    {
        public int DishId { get; set; }

         [Range(1, 100000, ErrorMessage="req")]  
        public  int? CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "req")]
        public string DishName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "req")]
        public string Description { get; set; } 
    }

public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "req")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }     

         public virtual ICollection<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
    }
```

and  view:

```
<label asp-for="Dish.CategoryId" class="control-label"> Categories </label>
   <select class="form-control" asp-for="Dish.CategoryId">
.....
 <span asp-validation-for="Dish.CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
```

and add server side validation too

```
public IActionResult Add(DishCategoriesModel model)
{  
   
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     //...your code
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change your view like below:

```
<form asp-action="Add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //...
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Dish.Category.CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select class="form-control" asp-for="Dish.Category.CategoryId">
            <option selected disabled>Select Category...</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
            {
                <option value="@item.CategoryId">@item.CategoryName</option>
            }
        </select>
                                //change here.....
        <span asp-validation-for="Dish.Category.CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    //...
</form>
```

Be sure add `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your razor view like below:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Result:

[image]